# XCode上の！マークについて

Tags: xcode, git

XCode8上の一部のファイルに!マークがついてしまう状態になってしまいました。

新しくクーロンしたり、一度消して再度登録しても同じ状態でした。

この!マークを解決する方法を教えていただけませんでしょうか。よろしくお願いいたします。[[image: 以下のようにpngファイルの一部に!マークがついてしまってます[1]]

Answer (score 3):

gitのクライアントソフトをお使いでしょうか？
でしたら何かのタイミングでステージされたものを一旦git resetで戻すと消えることがあります。

以前新規ファイルを追加して名前を変えたりしていたら同じようなことになり、sourcetreeのステージを解除したら!マークの表示が消えました。
ただcloneをした直後の場合にファイルの変更も何もないので知らない間に編集されてしまってたなどない限り関係ないかもしれません。

Answer (score 0):

！が検索できないので勘で書いていますが、
画像(png)に!があるという事は、そのファイルがコピーされていない可能性があります。
『if needed』を使えばコピーできるかもしれません。

・・・もし、『!』をクリックして何か文章が出るようであれば、それがエラーの原因でしょう。

Comment: !をクリックしｔ目お文章は出ませんでした。ファイル自体はローカル上にはクーロンできており、一度消して再度登録しても同じく！マークがついてしまいます。

Comment: 文章は出なかったと。では、そのファイルは配置できますか？